# Jquery remove attribute not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="image" name="Submit" src="Images/FormButtons/SubmitButton.gif" />
```

I want to remove the src attribute so i'm using the following function.

```
  <script>

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type=image]").removeAttr("src");
    });

  </script>
```

It works in firefox but doesnt work in IE? Any one know how to get it to work in IE?

Comment: Please specify the IE version and jQuery version that you're testing with. Your code works fine for me in IE11 with jQuery 1.11. ([see this jsFiddle to demonstrate it working](https://jsfiddle.net/7vfpsshw/2/))

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr()
>   doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. To
>   avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead:

```
$element.prop(
> "onclick", null ); console.log( "onclick property: ", $element[ 0
> ].onclick );
```

src: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using IE10

Answer (score 0):

I believe Your Image type will need parenthesis

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='image']").removeAttr("src");
});
```

Comment: Actually the attribute does get removed but in IE its leaves a small x kind of icon when viewed in browser but in firefox there is no x?